# Python3 - "UseDefaultCredentials" to access SSO protected Website with requests.get

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, single-sign-on

I want to access a website via Python3's requests module, but I always get an 401 Error.
Adding a user and password via requests.Session didn't help.

I neither know the SSO Implementation nor the SSO Server.

With Powershell there is a "UseDefaultCredentials" Flag that lets me access those websites easily.

Is there a way to also get those "Default Credentials" in Python too?

BR Chris